# Send push notification after time interval

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification

I want to send a [HTML push notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) in a specific time interval (e.g. every evening). Is this possible **without a server**? Can I set a timeout in my ServiceWorker, which then creates the push notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So think about what you are trying to do.  A website does not exist out of the context of someones browser.  Lets say you wrote some amazing javascript that would do what you want when you want.  Where would that code actively be running?

This type of action requires a server or a browser which is always and never close and runs javascript forever (the second choice is not the right one)

Comment: Hm, I thought that Service Workers could be capable of doing so. But this makes sense. Thanks!